# Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\pagina\PHP\CONEXION.PHP on line 7

Tags: php

Este es el código de conexión a mi db que es lo que que tengo que corregir

```
<?php

$conexion=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","")or die("no hay conexion");
$bd=mysqli_select_db("usuariosdb",$conexion) or die ("no existe la base de datos ");

 ?>
```

Comment: Por que no le pasas los 4 parámetros a mysqli_connect ??? -> https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.mysqli-connect.php

Comment: Siempre es bueno checar la doc. al respecto https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.select-db.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tu error se da porque estas pasando los parametros alreves

primero es la $conexion:

```
$conexion=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","")or die("no hay conexion");
$bd=mysqli_select_db($conexion,"usuariosdb") or die ("no existe la base de datos ");
```

referencia:

https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.select-db.php

Answer (score 0):

Prueba hacerlo de este modo mejor:

```
$conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","password", "database") or die("no hay conexion");
```

Por que ? Por la Nota que nos da select_database

> [Nota: Esta función debería ser usada solo para cambiar la base de
> datos por defecto para la conexión. Se puede seleccionar la base de
> datos por defecto en el cuarto parámetro de la función
> mysqli_connect().](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.select-db.php)